# Strip out special characters in php

Tags: php, special-characters

I have the code below:

```
<?php echo $fields->question; ?>
```

I specifically want to strip out any special characters that may cause an issue with php, how could I do that? Specifically "" is causing me a problem at the moment.

Comment: What special characters do you mean exactly? What issues are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo htmlentities($fields->question, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the addslashes() native PHP function?

```
$foo = addslashes($fields->question);
echo $foo;
```

This won't strip them out, but it should prevent them from causing you any problems by escaping the quotes.